# Update form on AJAX return

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

On my website I have a form that the user can fill out to update a record in the database, the form is below...

```
 <form class='bill-upd'>
             <input type='hidden' value='".$info['rand']."' name='rand2' id='rand2'>
             <input type='hidden' value='".$info['id']."' name='billid' id='billid'>
            Total <input type='text' id='total' name='total' title='".$info['bill']."' class='defaultText' /><br />
            Bill name<input type='text' id='bill-name' name='bill-name' title='".$info['bill_name']."' class='defaultText' /><br />
           bill descriptiion <input type='text' id='bill-description' name='bill-description' title='".$info['bill_description']."' class='defaultText'  /><br />
            category   <select id='bill-category' name='bill-category'>
                <option value='Household Bills'>Household Bills</option>
                <option value='Social Activities'>Social Activities</option>
            </select>
        <input type='button' value='Save' class='bill-upd-submit' />
        </form>
```

I then use AJAX to send this data to my table and update the record accordingly, ***this works fine***.

AJAX

```
 $(".bill-upd-submit").click(function() {
          var elem = $(this);
         $.post("update_bill.php", elem.parent(".bill-upd").serialize(), function(data) {
         // fade new data in
         elem.closest('li').html(data);
        });

    });
```

PHP

```
 $uid = $_SESSION['oauth_id'];
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['billid']);       
   $bill = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total']);
   $billname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bill-name']);
   $billdescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bill-description']);
   $billcolour  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bill-category']);
   $rand = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rand2']);



        #update Record
       $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `outgoings` SET id = '$id', user_id = '$uid', bill = '$bill', bill_name = '$billname', bill_description = '$billdescription', bill_colour = '$billcolour', rand = '$rand' WHERE user_id = '$uid' AND rand = '$rand' ") or die(mysql_error());






         Print "<span class='cost'>&pound;".$bill . "</span> ";
         Print "<h4 class='bill-name'>".$billname . "</h4> ";
         Print "<p class='bill-details'><span class='bill-category'>".$billdescription . "</span> "; 
         Print "<span class='bill-description'>". $billcolour . "</span></p>"; 
     echo "<a href='#' class='edit-bill'>edit</a> 

         <form class='bill-upd show'>
            <input type='hidden' value='".$rand."' name='rand2' id='rand2'>
            <input type='hidden' value='".$billname."' name='billid' id='billid''>
            Total <input type='text' title='".$bill."' id='total' name='total' value='".$bill."'/><br />
            Bill name<input type='text' id='bill-name' name='bill-name' value='".$billname."'/><br />
           bill descriptiion <input type='text' id='bill-description' name='bill-description' value='".$billdescription."'/><br />
            bill colour<input type='text' id='bill-colour' name='bill-colour'value='".$billcolour."'/>
          <input type='button' value='Save' class='bill-upd-submit' />
        </form>   

         <form class='delete-bill'>
             <input type='hidden' value='".$rand."' name='rand2' id='rand2'>

        <input type='button' value='delete' class='delete' />
        </form>   

         ";
```

Once updated my Ajax then returns the data all laid out as it should be, only this time around, If I fill the form out it doesnt update my table, If i refresh my page I can fill it out and it works however, has anybody an idea of what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Give your forms a name attribute and try again.  I read somewhere that missing form names might prevent ajax post from working.

Comment: If that doesn't work, and `.on()` doesn't work either, then you might have to re-add your ajax (between script tags), in the output of your php script.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are loading the content dynamically so your initial binding will not work for that. Use `jQuery on` for binding like this.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".bill-upd-submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this);
        $.post("update_bill.php", elem.parent(".bill-upd").serialize(), function(data){
           elem.closest('li').html(data);
        });    
     });
 });
```

jQuery `on` works for current and future elements (loaded via ajax or so).

http://api.jquery.com/on/

jQuery on is available from 1.7+ . So if you are using a version prior to that, conside `live`

Comment: Thanks @Shyju, still no luck however, the data doesn't seem to insert

Comment: @user766266 : Are you getting any script error ? What is the firebug console showing ?

Comment: It's not showing anything @shyju, with the code you provided however my update no longer works initially

Comment: Also, I do have multiple instances of this form on my page @shyju so could it be that the code you provided doesnt know which form to take the data from?

Comment: @user766266: You are not explicitly saying to serialize your form but the parent of clicked element.can you post  a jsfiddle ?

Comment: i just want to see the markup before and after( after ajax injected the content)